# LuaLaTeX 0.95+ needed--Novel Class--Commented Out Lines

Tags: luatex

I am trying to compile a file which requires LuaLaTeX 0.95+:

```
Error: Must compile with LuaLaTeX 0.95+
```

It looks like there's only 0.85 on my system.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85
```

The luatex.org web site doesn't have any OSX binaries.

How can I upgrade?

I found the error!! Even though I was using LuaLaTeX, there was a *commented out line* :

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
```

Even though this line was commented out, it prevented LuaLaTeX from running the novel class. The issue was not running an old or a new version of LuaLaTeX at all, it was the presence of a *commented out* line which prevented LuaLaTeX from running.

I thought that commented-out lines were ignored. Apparently not.

Comment: What happens if you open a command window and type `luatex -v`? On an up-to-date MacTeX2020 system, the answer at present should be `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)`.

Comment: You are correct. So what's happening?

Comment: Well, `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85` is not a binary at all. It's a directory which contains just one file, *viz.*, `luatex85.sty`. Unless you chose a nonstandard setup, MacTeX2020's binaries should all be in `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin`.

Comment: Do you maybe have more than one TeX distribution active on you Mac? Please advise.

Comment: Only one is active. I tried to go to  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85 but I'm on Mojave and I can't seem to get there. Hate these protections.

Comment: The novel package requires it.

Comment: It wasn't possible to post a MWE because the code immediately threw that error. In any event, I deleted the luatex 0.85.sty file, the Texlive 2020 directory it was in, ran sudo texhash (texhash wouldn't work) and the problem disappeared. Weird.

Comment: deleting that will break other documents it is part of texlive. I get no error from `\documentclass{novel}\begin{document}zzz\end{document}` using an unmodified texlive 2020.

Comment: as the class contains a `\RequirePackage{luatex85} ` it should actually error if you delete the sty.

Comment: Note there is no version called 0.95+ the message from novel class means any version 0.95 or greater, so the version 1.12 in texlive 2020 is suitable.

Comment: A commented out line was preventing LuaLaTeX from running. I thought commented out lines were ignored. Apparently not. I amended the question.

Comment: Please explain exactly how you were compiling as all the normal compilers ignores that line. Editors on the other hand... This is why you always compile in a terminal in such cases, to rule out interference from the editor.

Comment: I use Texshop, MacOS, TexLive 2020.  When I deleted that line, LuaLaTeX ran without throwing any errors. The difference between the MWE in the answer and my file was that line (and one hundred pages of text). So I removed that line and LuaLaTeX compiled the file.

Comment: I found the error. I was running LuaLaTeX. A commented out line was keeping LuaLaTeX from running. – user26732 M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
\documentclass{novel}\begin{document}zzz\end{document}
```

If you use pdflatex or xelatex then you get the error:

```
! Class novel Error: Must compile with LuaLaTeX 0.95+.

See the novel class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.76 ...uaLaTeX only. No pdfTeX, dvips, or XeTeX.}
                                                  
? h
Sorry, LuaLaTeX only. No pdfTeX, dvips, or XeTeX.
?
```

If you use lualatex then it runs without error

```
Output written on file.pdf (2 pages, 14973 bytes).
```

So it would appear that your error was not using lualatex.

---

If you look at the first few lines of terminal output from this test document then you will see

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./dd163.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5


 L3 programming layer <2020-09-03> (./novel.cls
Document Class: novel 2018/04/26 v1.52 LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty)
```

Note that the `luatex85` package is required by the `novel` class, so deleting it as suggested in comments will not help.

Comment: No, I was using LuaLatex. It wasn't possible to post a MWE because the code immediately threw that error. In any event, I deleted the luatex 0.85.sty file, the Texlive 2020 directory it was in, ran sudo texhash (texhash wouldn't work) and the problem disappeared. Weird.

Comment: @user26732 the code will have thrown the error immediately as it was not running under luatex. (You can look in the source code and see under what circumstances that message is given)

Comment: @user26732 the luatex85 package is required by `novel.cls` so deleting will not help.

Comment: @user26732 I have added the terminal output from the test document to my answer.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it might help someone else. In the meantime, I'm stickin' by my story.

Comment: I found the error. I was running LuaLaTeX. A commented out line was keeping LuaLaTeX from running.